# How to assign array fetched from an API to data property in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to fetch news articles from an external source, it returns JSON object. I want to assign its articles property to a variable in my component. Somehow this error is occurring.

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'articles' of undefined

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

```
export default {
  name: "blog",
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // API call
    this.fetchnews();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchnews(){
      fetch(
      "----------------------news link-------------------------"
    )
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json_data) {
        //console.log(typeof(json_data))
        this.articles = json_data.articles
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the first contributor properly noticed - the issue is `this.articles` inside your latest function doesn't really point to what you need.
If you are limited to ES5 then stick to the first answer.
However if you can use ES6 then simply get advantages of short syntax:

```js
export default {
  name: "blog",
  data() {
    return {
      articles: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // API call
    this.fetchnews();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchnews(){
      fetch("----------------------news link-------------------------")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json_data => this.articles = json_data.articles);
    }
  }
};
```

- in this case `this` will properly point to the outer scope.

Also why do you need two `then()`? You could collapse them into one:

```js
.then(response => this.articles = response.json().articles);
```

Comment: is this even composition API?  looks more like options API to me...

Comment: @RobertoDVLeonardo composition API didn't exist in Feb 2020 :))

Answer (score 1):

using `function` keyword creates new scope. if you use arrow syntax like `() => {}` you can use parent scope and set articles via `this.articles`

```
fetchnews(){
  fetch()
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((json_data) => {
    this.articles = json_data.articles
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in`this.articles`: here `this` refers to the function not vue instance , so you may define this outside the function like:

`let This=this`

and inside your function :

`This.articles = json_data.articles`
This here refers to  vue instance

Answer (score 0):

javascript `function` as global scope make sure use to assign function to variables